# ERROR: Connection Closed Gracefully

Tags: email, smtp, delphi-7

I have tried the below code for sending the mail, but it shows connection closed gracefully error. I have tried 587 and 465 port also. Authentication also raise the error for "5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. q27sm64805279pfi.83 - gsmtp".

```
uses
  IdSMTP, IdMessage, IdEMailAddress;

procedure SendSimpleMail;
var
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  IdMessage: TIdMessage;
  IdEmailAddressItem: TIdEmailAddressItem;
begin
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Port := 25;   // or 587    //or 465
    IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
    IdSMTP.Username := 'username@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Password := 'password';
    IdSMTP.Connect;
    if IdSMTP.Authenticate then
    begin
      IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
      try
        IdMessage.From.Name := 'User Name';
        IdMessage.From.Address := 'username@gmail.com';
        IdMessage.Subject := 'E-mail subject';
        IdMessage.Body.Add('E-mail body.');

        IdEmailAddressItem := IdMessage.Recipients.Add;
        IdEmailAddressItem.Address := 'recipient@email.com';

        IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
      finally
        IdMessage.Free;
      end;
    end;
    IdSMTP.Disconnect;
  finally
    IdSMTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To use `STARTTLS`, you need to

1. assign an SSLIOHandler component, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, to the `TIdSMTP.IOHandler` property. You will have to deploy the OpenSSL DLLs with your app, if not already installed on the target machine that will be running your app.
2. set the `TIdSMTP.UseTLS` property to `utUseExplicitTLS` to enable `STARTTLS` handling. Make sure `TIdSMTP.UseEHLO` is true (it is by default) so `TIdSMTP` can discover whether the server supports `STARTTLS`.
3. connect to port 587.

Try this:

```
uses
  IdSMTP, IdMessage, IdEMailAddress, IdSSLOpenSSL;

procedure SendSimpleMail;
var
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  IdMessage: TIdMessage;
  IdEmailAddressItem: TIdEmailAddressItem;
  IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdSMTP);
    IdSMTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
    IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Port := 587;
    IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
    IdSMTP.Username := 'username@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Password := 'password';
    IdSMTP.Connect;
    if IdSMTP.Authenticate then
    begin
      IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
      try
        IdMessage.From.Name := 'User Name';
        IdMessage.From.Address := 'username@gmail.com';
        IdMessage.Subject := 'E-mail subject';
        IdMessage.Body.Add('E-mail body.');

        IdEmailAddressItem := IdMessage.Recipients.Add;
        IdEmailAddressItem.Address := 'recipient@email.com';

        IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
      finally
        IdMessage.Free;
      end;
    end;
    IdSMTP.Disconnect;
  finally
    IdSMTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Update**: the code above is meant for Indy 10.  If you are using Indy 9 instead, there are some differences.

1. The OpenSSL component was named `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket`.
2. `TIdSMTP` did not support `STARTTLS` yet. You would have to manage the `SSLIOHandler's`PassThrough` property manually.

If you connect to port 587 for explicit TLS, you have to set `PassThrough` to true initially so you connect to the server unencrypted, then send the `STARTTLS` command manually and set `PassThrough` to false to activate encryption before sending any further SMTP commands.

```
Procedure SendMail();
begin
  IdSMTP1.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.AuthenticationType := atLogin;
  IdSMTP1.Port := 587;
  IdSMTP1.Username := 'user@gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.Password := 'password';
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.PassThrough := True;
  IdSMTP1.Connect;
  try
    IdSMTP1.SendCmd('STARTTLS', [220]);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.PassThrough := False;
    IdSMTP1.SendCmd('EHLO ' + IdSMTP1.LocalName);
    IdSMTP1.Authenticate;
    IdMessage1.Body.Add('Test Message');
    IdMessage1.From.Address := 'frommail@gmail.com';
    IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'tomail@gmail.com';
    IdMessage1.Subject := 'Hi';
    try
      IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
    except
      ShowMessage('Error : email not send');
    end;
  finally
    IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

If you connect to port 465 for implicit SSL, all you have to do is set `PassThrough` to false before connecting to the server. The connection will be initially encrypted before sending any SMTP commands at all, no `STARTTLS` needed.

```
Procedure SendMail();
begin
  IdSMTP1.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.AuthenticationType := atLogin;
  IdSMTP1.Port := 465;
  IdSMTP1.Username := 'user@gmail.com';
  IdSMTP1.Password := 'password';
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.PassThrough := False;
  IdSMTP1.Connect;
  try
    IdMessage1.Body.Add('Test Message');
    IdMessage1.From.Address := 'frommail@gmail.com';
    IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'tomail@gmail.com';
    IdMessage1.Subject := 'Hi';
    try
      IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
    except
      ShowMessage('Error : email not send');
    end;
  finally
    IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Here I am using delphi 7.0 it will not support TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL dll, so i can change the coding as like this. Since i got the same error message in this code.

Comment: Here I am using Indy version 9.00.10. It shows "Could not load SSL library." error. Port : 587 and also I have tried for port 465 coding it also raise the error "Connection closed gracefully".

Comment: Also I have attached the component details screen shot for my question.

Comment: @Barani: Indy has a `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit which returns why Indy could not load OpenSSL at runtime. Either it could not find the OpenSSL DLLs, or it could not find one or more expected functions being exported from the DLLs. Indy 9 requires customized OpenSSL DLLs (which are available at https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/), it does not use the standard DLLs. That change was made in Indy 10 (which you *really* should upgrade to).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Here I am using delphi 7.0 it will support TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL dll, so i can change the coding as like this. Since i got the same error message in this code.

```
Procedure SendMail();
    var Resp : integer;
    begin
            IdSMTP1.Host :='smtp.gmail.com';
            IdSMTP1.AuthenticationType:= atLogin;
            IdSMTP1.Port := 587;
            IdSMTP1.Username := 'user@gmail.com';
            IdSMTP1.Password := 'password';
            IdSMTP1.Connect;
            if IdSMTP1.Connected then
            Begin
                Resp:= -1;
                Resp:= IdSMTP1.SendCmd('STARTTLS',Resp);
                IdMessage1.Body.Add('Tets Message');
                IdMessage1.From.Address              := 'frommail@gmail.com';
                IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'tomail@gmail.com';
                IdMessage1.Subject  := 'Hi';
                try
                IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
                except
                  ShowMessage('Error : email not send');
                end;
                IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
            end;
    end;
```

Comment: I assume you are using the (very outdated) version of Indy that shipped with your Delphi 7?  You really need to upgrade to a modern version of Indy. As for the version you have, I have updated my answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was helped:

When sending mail, a server error occurs:

> '501 Syntactically invalid EHLO argument (s)' (error code 0x800CCC63).

This error occurs if the name of the computer (running Windows) contains invalid characters:
``` (`` {_} '', Russian letters or spaces) ```.
[Have a look on naming files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

It should be changed via:
`Control Panel> Network> Authentication`.

It is also necessary to check the name specified through:
`Control Panel> Network> TCP`

Comment: This answer as its written does not reflect any solution requested by the OP. Either modify your question by editing the required information to link it to the question or remove your answer.